# returning wrong nested dictionary values from VBA-JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, dictionary

*Solved: see comment by @CDP1802*

The code below converts json-->Excel-->json using VBA-JSON. It returns values properly from a dictionary nested 1-deep, but it doesn't return values properly from a dictionary nested 2-deep. Instead, the resulting output.json repeats just the final sub-dictionary value.

What am I doing wrong?

The wrong nested-dictionary value is shown in red here:
[image]

Below is my code, which can be run using the input.json download from [here](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) assuming [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) is present.

```
Option Explicit
Sub jsonToExcelToJson()
'requires Tools > references > Microsoft scripting runtime
Dim JSON As Object, jsonText As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject, JsonTS As TextStream
Dim coll As New Collection, dict As New Dictionary
Dim subDict1 As New Dictionary, subDict2 As New Dictionary
Dim r As Range, sh As Worksheet, path As String
Dim hdr() As String, i As Integer
Const h = "id,username,city,website,latitude,longitude"
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set r = sh.Range("A1")
hdr = Split(h, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(hdr) 'make header
  r.Offset(0, i) = hdr(i)
Next i
Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\input.json"        'input .json file
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(path, ForReading)
jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set JSON = ParseJson(jsonText)
For Each dict In JSON             'read json into Excel
    r.Offset(0, 0) = dict("id")
    r.Offset(0, 1) = dict("username")
    r.Offset(0, 2) = dict("address")("city")
    r.Offset(0, 3) = dict("website")
    r.Offset(0, 4) = dict("address")("geo")("lat")
    r.Offset(0, 5) = dict("address")("geo")("lng")
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Next
Set r = sh.Range("A2") 'below header
While r <> ""                    'write excel table to json
  dict("id") = r.Offset(0, 0)
  dict("username") = r.Offset(0, 1)
  subDict1("city") = r.Offset(0, 2)
  dict("website") = r.Offset(0, 3)
  subDict2("lat") = r.Offset(0, 4)
  subDict2("lng") = r.Offset(0, 5)
  subDict1.Add "geo", subDict2
  dict.Add "address", subDict1
  MsgBox (dict("address")("geo")("lat"))
  coll.Add dict
  Set dict = Nothing: Set subDict1 = Nothing: Set subDict1 = Nothing
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\output.json" 'output .json file
Open path For Output As #1
Print #1, ConvertToJson(coll, Whitespace:=2)
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set subDict1 = Nothing: Set subDict1 = Nothing` ? Shouldn't one be subDict2 ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Thank you -- this is the solution. I don't know whether you want to post it as a solution, so I can give you credit? Or do you think I should remove my post because it was something so stupid? In any event, I really was stumped. Thanks!

Comment: It's OK leave it posted, I'm happy to have helped.